# Returning two substrings from a string

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, substring

In searching a pre-populated ArrayList, call it

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String>();
```

I am trying to add new elements to it based on these elements containing certain regex values. I am having success when I just need to return one substring of the element. For example, if I have

```
String removable = "X";
```

which resides in an element, call it

```
ABCDX
```

the    X     is easily removed and added to the ArrayList with the code

```
   if(myList.get(i).length() == 5 && myList.get(i).substring(4,5).contains(removable))
   {
            myList.add(i+1, myList.get(i).substring(0, 4));
   }
```

but when I have an element such as

```
ABXCD ,
```

which I presumed could be handled with

```
 if(myList.get(i).length() == 5 && myList.get(i).substring(2,3).contains(removable))
   {
            myList.add(i+1, myList.get(i).substring(0, 2).substring(3, 5));
   }
```

I get a String Index Out of Bounds Exception. How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code example you are using

```
abc1List.get(i)
```

should this not be

```
myList.get(i)
```

**Edit**

I believe your problem is that you are substring'ing a substring. Your code does this

```
myList.get(i).substring(0, 2).substring(3, 5)
```

So what that is saying is, get the substring of a string, then get a substring of the previously retrieved substring. Since the first substring is only 2 characters long, the second substring returns out of bounds as you are trying to start from index 3 which does not exist.

Your code pretty much evaluates to:

```
"ABXCD ,".substring(0,2) = "AB"

"AB".substring(3,5) = Out of bounds substring retrieval!
```

You need to do something like

```
myList.get(i).substring(0, 2) + myList.get(i).substring(3, 5)
```

or find an alternative method of doing what you want.

Comment: @ Lee   Eureka! Worked perfectly!! +1

Answer (score 0):

after you check if it contains `X` then use

```
string = string.replaceAll("X","");
```

and then add it to the List

Comment: @ MaVRoSCy in more specified terms, I'm more interested in whether or not `.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex).substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` is even legal in Java String class to begin with :/  Eclipse doesn't show any errors and I couldn't find any answers in previously posted questions.

Answer (score 0):

`abc1List.get(i).substring(0, 2).substring(3, 5)` seems wrong.
You do not intend to take substring of substring?
You want something like:

```
myList.add(i+1,abc1List.get(i).substring(0, 2));
myList.add(i+2,abc1List.get(i).substring(3, 5));
```

Comment: @ Sameer Right but the issue is that I need it to reside in the same index/element

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed the problem is with forming substring of another substring.
As substring(0, 2)conatins only 3 characters forming another substring with greter length will give the error.
You can use the + operator to concatenate 2 substrings